# Why is my API not printing out to the textbox?

Tags: c#, json, visual-studio, restsharp

So after understanding how to get the API to work I managed to set it up so it prints out data to labels flawlessly. Now when I try to do the same thing but with a different API (Almost the same one) it decides not to print it out, feels like I missed some code, is it just me?

The first ticker (Update_BTC_Ticker) works flawlessly, it prints out as it should but the other one (Update_BTC_Trades) does not want to print out, what did I miss out?

```
private void Update_BTC_Ticker(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://btc-e.com/api");
    var request = new RestRequest("2/btc_usd/ticker", Method.GET);
    //request.AddHeader("Key", "46G9R9D6-WJ77XOIP-XH9HH5VQ-A3XN3YOZ-8T1R8I8T");
    request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

    IRestResponse<BtcUsdTicker> response = client.Execute<BtcUsdTicker>(request);

    sellLabel.Text = Convert.ToString(response.Data.ticker.sell);
    buyLabelTrue.Text = Convert.ToString(response.Data.ticker.buy);


}



private void Update_BTC_Trades(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var client = new RestClient("https://btc-e.com/api");
    var request = new RestRequest("2/btc_usd/trades", Method.GET);
    //request.AddHeader("Key", "46G9R9D6-WJ77XOIP-XH9HH5VQ-A3XN3YOZ-8T1R8I8T");
    request.OnBeforeDeserialization = resp => { resp.ContentType = "application/json"; };

    IRestResponse<BtcTradeTicker> response = client.Execute<BtcTradeTicker>(request);

    textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(response.Data.tradeTicker.price);


}





public class BtcUsdTicker
{
    public Ticker ticker { get; set; }
}

public class Ticker
{

    public float high { get; set; }
    public float low { get; set; }
    public float avg { get; set; }
    public float vol { get; set; }
    public float vol_cur { get; set; }
    public float last { get; set; }
    public float buy { get; set; }
    public float sell { get; set; }
    public int updated { get; set; }
    public int server_time { get; set; }



}


public class BtcTradeTicker
{
    public tradeTicker tradeTicker { get; set; }
}


public class tradeTicker
{
    public int date { get; set; }
    public double price { get; set; }
    public double amount { get; set; }
    public int tid { get; set; }
    public string price_currency { get; set; }
    public string item { get; set; }
    public string trade_type { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're calling the method correctly? If you set a break point inside `Update_BTC_Trades`, is it being hit and is the response is what you expect?

Comment: I will try that out!

Comment: It doesnt seem to hit the breakpoint, thats weird

Comment: You've got some sort of event binding that's missing or just not working (e.g. a button click or a timer). See if you can figure out how the other method is being called, and figure out how to duplicate that for your new method.

Comment: Well I do have this timer but I dont thank that it has such a big effect does it?
            timer1 = new Timer();
            timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Update_BTC_Ticker);
            timer1.Interval = 2000;
            timer1.Start();

Comment: Yeah that's it. That causes your `Update_BTC_Ticker` method to be called every 2 seconds. You can just piggy-back on that timer by adding a new line `timer1.Tick += new EventHandler(Update_BTC_Trades);`.

Comment: But I dont see how that can stop my other method from running, now it reaches the method but it gave me this error, im not so good with error handleing.
https://i.gyazo.com/89f5ff4e0dae5fdcb82e2068d1ee3f33.png

Comment: That's because the result was not what you expected to it to be (either empty or some other format that couldn't be parsed correctly). Again set a breakpoint before that point and inspect the response. If need be, go back and review the API documentation.

Comment: As you probably already understood, Im not the guy who uses the debugger too often, I should really start doing it, I will be back with more information!

Comment: @p.s.w.g I looked over the [GitHub Docs](https://github.com/DmT021/BtceApi) and the [Restsharp Examples](http://restsharp.org/) and I really cant locate whats wrong, Im pretty sure im parsing it wrong but as I am new to this API and new to API's in general its kinda confusing.